# How i can use 2 forms in one page and when click in first submit button show something in second form

Tags: php

Image of page: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bS2qc.png

Image of database values: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bS2qc.png#1

When i click in submit button of first form I want to show the values of one row in database in the second form, for example  i put in first form -> id and in textbox value 1 and i click in submit button i want to show the values of that row in the textboxes of the second form like this -> http : // imgur.com / 5ayOGMj (without spaces)

Code:

```
<form method="post" action="#">
                    <p>Mostrar evento por:</p>
                    <p>
                        <select name="select" id="select">
                            <option selected="selected">id</option>
                            <option>Nome do Evento</option>
                            <option>Data do Evento</option>
                        </select>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <input type="text" name="nomeEvento" id="text" width="300">
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Mostrar">
                    </p>
                </form>
                <?php
                require ('sql_connect.php');

                if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
                    $selectedItem = mysql_escape_string($_POST['select']);
                    $nomeEvent = mysql_escape_string($_POST['nomeEvento']);

                    if (!$_POST['select'] | !$_POST['nomeEvento'])
                    {
                        echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
                            window.alert('Tem de meter um username e uma password')
                            window.location.href='UpdateEvents.php'
                            </SCRIPT>");
                        exit();
                    }

                    $query = "SELECT * FROM `eventos` WHERE '$selectedItem' = '$nomeEvent'";
                    $result = mysql_query($query);

                    if (!$result) die ("Database access failed: " . mysql_error());

                    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                    {
                        $coiso1 = $row['nome'];
                        $coiso2 = $row['data'];
                        $coiso3 = $row['descricao'];
                    }

                }                   
                ?>                
                <form method="get" action="#">
                  <p>Nome do Evento:</p>
                  <p>
                    <input name="text1" type="text" id="text" width="300" value="<?php $coiso1 ?>">
                  </p>
                  <p>Data do Evento:</p>
                  <p>
                    <input type="text" name="text" id="text2" width="300">
                  </p>
                  <p>Descrição:</p>
                  <p>
                    <input type="text" name="text2" id="text3" width="300">
                  </p>
                  <p>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit2" value="Alterar">
                  </p>
                </form>
```

Comment: Easiest way is to use `JavaScript` to do that, or collect form data from `$_POST` and input it into other form, like this: `<input type='text' value="<?php echo $_POST['val']; ?>"/>`. Anyway, and MOST IMPORTANT - try to learn simple framework instead of struggling with pure `php` and making your code dramatically less readable and elastic. `CakePHP` or `CodeIgniter` will really do, they are easy to learn and you will absolutely love them as your first framework :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery ajax to submit the first form and on success update values in second form using jquery

Answer (score 0):

You forgot an **echo** probably:

```
<input name="text1" type="text" id="text" width="300" value="<?php echo $coiso1 ?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove 'action="#"' from 1st form to locate form submiting to the same place and get any data from $_POST after reload. If u no need page reload use ajax.